# How to handle large CSV files to insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, insert

I have a file a csv file (made as .txt) that I am currently parsing right now, but the file is about 350mb uncompressed. When it's zipped, it shows in the zip file as 23mb. My system completely freezes when I try to parse the 350mb file. I store the lines in an array like this. The first row are the headings.

```
$fh = fopen($inputFile, 'r');
    $contents = fread($fh, filesize($inputFile)); // 5KB
fclose($fh);
//$contents = str_replace('"','',$contents);

$fileLines = explode("\n", $contents); // explode to make sure we are only using the first line.
```

Then I go through each line to insert it in a loop into mySQL. Since the file is about 350mb, would there be a way to parse it from the .zip file like .zip_filename.txt or would that even make a difference at all?

The file is too large to insert directly into mysql through the import method.

Comment: it's `MB` (or `MiB`) but neither `mB` nor `mb`.

Comment: `$contents = fread($fh, filesize($inputFile));` - this is most definitely what you do NOT want to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($inputFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Also use multi insert if possible. Instead of running multiple queries:

```
insert into table (col1, col2) values("row1-col1", "row1-col2");
insert into table (col1, col2) values("row2-col1", "row2-col2");
```

Building one query like this is much quicker:

```
insert into table (col1, col2) 
values ("row1-col1", "row1-col2"),
       ("row2-col1", "row2-col2");
```

By the way, you can also [load a file directly into mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

```
load data local infile 'file.csv' into table table_name fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(col1, col2)
```

Comment: I used the fgetcsv function before, but it was worse then the fread. It wouldn't load the entire file and I tried adjusting the memory etc and no luck. There are millions of rows of data that need to be stored.

Comment: You may want to break them up into batches then

Comment: @user1701252 If it doesn't read the whole thing, perhaps some lines were longer than 1000 chars? You can let `fgetcsv()` determine how much to parse by passing `0` as `$length`.

Comment: What would be the best way to batch them? I'm just trying something out right now and I stored the insert statements into an array. Would I do a for loop from here and just change the number of $x? So for the first batch I could do 

for ($x=0;$x<count($num_rows);$x++)

Comment: @Jack Would I need to set up a unique key in mysql then so it doesn't insert the same rows twice/3 times? If fgetcsv stops itself, then I won't know which row it left off at and if it is inserting new rows or not. Sorry, but a little confused on this.

Comment: @user1701252 `fgetcsv()` doesn't stop itself first of all, and second, I would probably use transactions or let MySQL handle the CSV import :)

Comment: As suggested by SanderRows I created the file to output something more on the lines of insert into table (col1, col2) 
values ("row1-col1", "row1-col2"),
       ("row2-col1", "row2-col2"); but I am now getting this error on the mysql_query($insert) line. 

Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=7244 

Any ideas on this?

Comment: @user1701252 You might have reached your max_allowed_packet which you can find in your /etc/my.cnf. Either increase that value or run the query every x (1000 for instance) rows.

Comment: @SanderRoes Your method worked! This is what I did to solve the problem: 

Created a loop to create individual arrays of the values like this

insert into table (col1, col2) 
values ("row1-col1", "row1-col2"),
       ("row2-col1", "row2-col2");

Then I chunked the arrays into a thousand per array, and then ran the query. It inserted 4.7 million records successfully in about 10-15 minutes. 

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html), that'll allow you to insert the contents of a CSV file directly.